# Amazon Cognito throwing 500 internal server error on authentication

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-ecs

So I have an application that I am deploying through a docker container in ECS service. And I am using Amazon Cognito through application load balancer for authenticating into the application.

When I configured this with `internet-facing` Application Load Balancer(ALB), everything worked fine. But now when I changed my ALB to `internal`, it is throwing an error 500 Internal Server Error.

Has anyone seen similar scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was by adding a rule on Load balancer listener - `On Unauthenticated - allow`